# Berkeley DB android version download

Tags: android, berkeley-db

I have been looking for android version of Berkeley DB i have downloaded version 6.4.25 but cannot find the android version.
Can anyone tell me where to find it, beside oracle has been saying that Berkeley is supported on android.
https://blogs.oracle.com/berkeleydb/entry/berkeley_db_and_mobile_now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should download [.tar.gz](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html) Berkeley DB version. After that you have to migrate you DB. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/installation/build_android_intro.html#build_android) is instructions.

After that, you have to build the Android JDBC driver using the DB version that you have downloaded. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/installation/build_android_jdbc.html) is documented all the process and an example of how you could use it.

Comment: Thank you, i was thinking that the jar is available out of the box, i am now following the steps to create the DB driver, thank you